# How to change the layout of QueryableFilterRepeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I am using an **ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities web application** which contains a **QueryableFilterRepeater** server control inside the content placeholder on page **List.aspx**, when I execute the website, the filter control shows all the filters (**Label Name along with the corresponding Drop Down**) vertically.

[image: The current layout (vertical)]

Is there any way we can change the layout and display the filters horizontally?

Please find the .aspx code below

```
 <asp:QueryableFilterRepeater runat="server" ID="FilterRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DisplayName") %>' OnPreRender="Label_PreRender" />
    <asp:DynamicFilter runat="server" ID="DynamicFilter" OnFilterChanged="DynamicFilter_FilterChanged" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:QueryableFilterRepeater>
```

The corresponding .cs file code:-

```
protected void Label_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label label = (Label)sender;
            DynamicFilter dynamicFilter = (DynamicFilter)label.FindControl("DynamicFilter");
            QueryableFilterUserControl fuc = dynamicFilter.FilterTemplate as QueryableFilterUserControl;
            if (fuc != null && fuc.FilterControl != null)
            {
                label.AssociatedControlID = fuc.FilterControl.GetUniqueIDRelativeTo(label);
            }
        }

protected void DynamicFilter_FilterChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = 0;
        }
```

Need suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually wrap the  control in a span element and then use CSS to style it the way that i want:

```
<asp:QueryableFilterRepeater runat="server" ID="FilterRepeater">
<ItemTemplate>
    <span class="filter">
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DisplayName") %>' OnPreRender="Label_PreRender" />
        <asp:DynamicFilter runat="server" ID="DynamicFilter" OnFilterChanged="DynamicFilter_FilterChanged"/>&nbsp;
    </span>
</ItemTemplate>
```